# How to edit HTML extension file in VS Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

when I create a .html file in vs code, a new file is created but I can't write any code in it or edit it. How can I fix this? [.html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXqCj.png)

I searched about the issue on youtube but I only found about the emmet solutions which is not the main issue. I found that to avoid this problem I've to use .htm extension instead of .html extension.[the .htm file, which is editable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKR7s.png)

Comment: Do you see anything that looks related in the output logs? (View > Output)

Comment: If you use any extensions for VSCode, try to disable them one by one. Looks like something is breaking normal VSCode work

Comment: thanks, the editor was not selected for the HTML file so it was opening in chrome